# how to call success message after $location.path()

Tags: angularjs

Hello I am put my data on api and after that i called $location.path.it is working. I want to  display message after it $location reload. Can any one help

```
   $http.put(settings.WebApiBaseUrl + "api/abc/", save).success(function (data) {                    
               $location.path('/edit/'));
           $scope.success="Saved"
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {                    
                    $scope.errorMessage = "Error. }                     

            });
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#events start with these events in the docs

Comment: The answer depends on the router that you are using. If you are not using a router there is a different answer.